# How to make able to scroll ListView inside SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

How to make able to scroll listview inside `SingleChildScrollView`?

That's right, normally the list view scrolls even if the parent is a `SingleChildScrollView`.

But my case is special because I used

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification is UserScrollNotification) {
          if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
                //trigger doing some event ...
                ...changing screen because of this event
```

So my Listview scrolling is absolutely doing nothing and changing the screen because of the parent event.

```
child: ListView.builder( ... // when scroll it doesn`t scroll and change screen because of parent
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Can you include the full widget

Comment: you can use Slivers to achieve nested list things...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not provided the physics property for the list view:
Use -> `physics:AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` for the listview to make it scrollable.

Comment: That doesn`t work dude I already did it

Comment: Didi you try putting it in a container or expanded widget